# How clean a X509 certified file

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I made a routine to sign some proprietary binary files with PKCS#7 X509 certificates. The routine is functioning like a charm:

```
    public static byte[] SignFile(X509Certificate2Collection certs, byte[] data, bool Tipo_A3 = false)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
            if (VerifySign(data))
            {
                signedCms.Decode(data);
            }
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
            {

                CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner( cert);
                signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
                signer.SignerIdentifierType = SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber;

                signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(System.DateTime.Now));

                if (Type_A3 == true)
                {
                    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
                }

            }
            return signedCms.Encode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

My problem is related to RECOVER the original info. An 1Kb file will be transformed in a ~8Kb file, since the signature in within this file.

I need to read the data *without the signature/certificate* within the file, I mean, I need to recover the original data before its signing - and I don't know how to do it.

I saw that the signed file has bytes BEFORE and AFTER its original contents (I made a test using a tiny TXT file with "abcd"), but I'm affraid to consider ever the same data length before and after the original data to extract it.

I know I get the original content using this function, where DATA is the signed file:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
 using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

     public static Int VerifyContentInfo(byte[] data)
        {
           try
           {
            SignedCms signed = new SignedCms();
            signed.Decode(data);
            signed.CheckSignature(true);

            return signed.ContentInfo.Content.Length

           }
             catch
           {
             return null;
           }

        }
```

**The problem: even knowing the length of the original data within the signed file, how securely locate and extract it using a .NET function?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `signed.ContentInfo.Content` (whose value you took the length of) should be the original content.  Are you seeing something else there?

Comment: WOW! How didn't I see this? @bartonjs, write it in an answer to allow my vote. And thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, it seemed like it had to have obviously been not working, hence starting with a comment rather than an answer :).

Comment: :)  sometimes these things happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signed.ContentInfo.Content` (whose value you took the length of) is the original content.